# Integrating the Fractional Part of a Logarithm in a Laplace Transform

Tags: integration

I've had trouble with this integral and others that come along with it:
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty\{\log_a(x)\}e^{-xt}dx=\frac{1}{2t}
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty\{\log_a(x/t)\}e^{-x}dx=\frac12,
$$
where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part function. I don't know if it's actually the solution, but if it isn't then it's remarkably close and consistent. So far, the best I could do is write $\{x\}$ as a Fourier Series and integrate from there, but it ends up with an extra term that I can't drop. Here's that method in case it might help:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int\limits_0^\infty\{\log_a(x)\}e^{-tx}dx &=
\int\limits_0^\infty\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\sin(2\pi k\log_a(x))}{\pi k} e^{-tx}dx
\\&=
\int\limits_0^\infty\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{e^{2\pi k\log_a(x)i}-e^{-2\pi k\log_a(x)i}}{2\pi ki} e^{-tx}dx
\\&=
\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(1-e^{-2\pi\log_a(x)i}\right)-\log_a\left(1-e^{2\pi\log_a(x)i}\right)}{2\pi i} e^{-tx}dx
\\&=
\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\pi i-2\pi\log_a(x)i}{2\pi i} e^{-tx}dx
\\&=
\frac{1}{2t}+\frac{\gamma+\ln(t)}{\ln(a)t}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
You can also write it as a sum with $e^{-a^nz}$.